# How to run the next command automatically in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I'm developing an angular-android application, so I have to run some commands in the cmd. My system has minimal specifications since the commands take some time to run, I have to keep on monitoring it. To reduce the time and concentrate on my other things I put some command in the batch file. For example

```
ng build
cordova clean browser
cordova build browser 
cordova run browser
```

I put the above commands and save it as a batch file. When I run this file it only executes first command `ng build`, it doesn't automatically jump to second line. Previously I used mac, in that I save these as `.sh` file and when I execute them, all the command inside that executed successfully. What should I do to execute next commands automatically in the batch file? Thank you.

Comment: I think the first command failed...

Comment: No, It was executed successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some like this:

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call ng &&^
call cordova clean browser &&^
call cordova build browser &&^
call cordova run browser 
endlocal && goto :EOF

rem :: or in one line ::

call ng && (call cordova clean browser && (call cordova build browser &&(call cordova run browser)))
```

---

- Or ...

  ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_run=ok"
call ng && for %%i in ("clean browser","build browser","run browser
)do if "!_run!" == "ok" call cordova %%~i || set "_run="
endlocal && goto :EOF
```

---

In **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** you can use the **[&, |, &&](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) and [||](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)** ***operator***, also **combine them**...

---

```
commandA &  commandB                    Run commandA and then run commandB
commandA && commandB                    Run commandA, if it succeeds then run commandB
commandA || commandB                    Run commandA, if it fails then run commandB
commandA && commandB || commandC        If commandA succeeds run commandB, if it fails commandC
```

---

[Operator/Syntax Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) in **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**

Comment: Even if it works, it's dangerous, because if `ng` and  `cordova` are batch files, then they implicitly exit the batch-file context to command-line context. That leads into strange side effects

Comment: @jeb, i've not know this is bat files.. know i understand the call suggetion

Comment: You'd need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) to make it work as intended or avoid it by using `if defined _run`

Comment: @Stephan Danke schön!

Answer (score 0):

add start before each of those commands

```
  start ng build 
  start cordova clean browser 
  start cordova build browser  
  start cordova run browser
```

Comment: It executes all the command at the same time. I want to execute  second command, after the first command executed successfully.

Comment: Oops. Missed that one.